# How to remember password field in Sitecore custom user profile?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I've come across an annoying problem with the custom properties added to Sitecore User Profile.

I've added a password field to the custom user profile, but this field will not prepopulate the value on load, so if I make changes to other fields and save, it will overwrite the existing password with a blank, unless I type in the password again on every edit.

For example,

Custom User Profile original saved data:
1. phone number = 123.456.7890
2. password = 1234

Edit phone number only and save:
1. phone number = 123.123.1234
2. password = [blank]

The problem is because the password field always display as blank on loading, is there a way to make this field fetch the data and mask it?  Or do we have to overwrite the existing Sitecore field resolver class to ignore blank space?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like configuration issue. Field should be populated. Could you provide code you use for adding field?

Comment: @horseman I've follow the section 3.4 of Sitecore Security API on extending the default user profile.  So all I've done is adding fields to the default user profile template in the core database.  The field type I've added for the password is "Password" field type. [link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/security_api_cookbook_usletter.pdf)

Comment: As a rule, the password are stored hashed, so there is no way to retrieve original password and then "mask" it.
You probably need to use custom field that will change password only if it contains data.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander, but I don't think the "Password" field hash the stored password.  Because I am retrieving the stored password via API to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with Sitecore documents...

There is no way to handle this without rewriting the Security API.  As the user profile template only handles basic text field type.